# In VSIX Visual Studio Extensibility How do you get whether a Parameter of a Function is an 'ref', 'out' or value type

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, vs-extensibility

My Function in the Project I run the VSIX in is this;

```
        public void Method1(string name, out int age)
        {
            age = 0;
            int g1 = 0;
            //
            int g = 0;
        }
```

And the VSIX Project Code to go over the Function Parameters is

```
//  Here 'codeElement' is the Function Having Parameters.
                    foreach (CodeElement codeElement2 in codeElement.Children)
                    {
                        if (codeElement2.Kind == vsCMElement.vsCMElementParameter)
                        {
                            string parameterName = codeElement2.Name;
                            string parameterDataType = ((CodeParameter)codeElement2).Type.AsString;
                            VsShellUtilities.ShowMessageBox(
                                this.package,
                                ">>>>>" + " : " + parameterName + " : " + parameterDataType,
                                "MESSAGE...",
                                OLEMSGICON.OLEMSGICON_INFO,
                                OLEMSGBUTTON.OLEMSGBUTTON_OK,
                                OLEMSGDEFBUTTON.OLEMSGDEFBUTTON_FIRST);
                        }
                    }
```

This code works fine and it gives the name of the Parameter and its DataType.

How can you get whether the Parameter is 'out', 'ref' or value type?

(Like the parameter 'age' in Method1 is an 'out')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [CodeParameter2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte80.codeparameter2?view=visualstudiosdk-2017) interface which contains more info:

```
((CodeParameter2)codeElement2).ParameterKind
```